# vue 3 phaser and spine.js - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

Tags: vuejs3, phaser-framework, spine.js, phaserjs

I'm trying to build a game with vue3 js phaser and spine . I've used the official template from phaser with vue and installed phaser-spine and import it .
https://phaser.io/news/2024/02/official-phaser-3-and-vue-3-template

this is the main.js file :

```
import { Lootbox } from './scenes/Lootbox';
import Phaser from 'phaser';
import {SpinePlugin} from "@esotericsoftware/spine-phaser"



// Find out more information about the Game Config at:
// https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.70.0/Phaser.Types.Core.GameConfig
const config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 1024,
    height: 768,
    parent: 'game-container',
    backgroundColor: '#028af8',
    plugins: {
        scene: [
           { key: 'spine.SpinePlugin', plugin: SpinePlugin, mapping: 'spine' }
        ]
     },
    scene: [game]
};


const StartGame = (parent) => {

    return new Phaser.Game({ ...config, parent });
}

export default StartGame;
```

and this is the scene file :

```
import Phaser from 'phaser';


export class Lootbox extends Phaser.Scene {
    constructor() {
        super('Lootbox');
    }

    preload() {
        this.load.spineBinary("man-data", "assets/man.skel");
        this.load.spineAtlas("man-atlas", "assets/man.atlas");
        console.log("scene loaded ")
    }

    create() {
        const manAnimation = this.add.spine(333, 333, 'man-data', "idle", true);
        manAnimation.animationState.setAnimation(0, "in", true)

    }

   
}
```

Now i see my atlas an skel file loaded in the network tab and the png but i keep getting this error
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

on this line

```
        const lootbox = this.add.spine(333, 333, 'lootbox-data', "idle", true);
```

I've tried using vanilla js and it works there, but i want to make the project with vuejs 3 . So the assets are ok and working when using a vanilla js project .

From what i understand i try to initiate spine to early?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import * as spine from "@esotericsoftware/spine-phaser"

plugins: {
        scene: [
            { key: "spine.SpinePlugin", plugin: spine.SpinePlugin, mapping: "spine" }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, i did , same result. I did do a change 
from const manAnimation = this.add.spine(333, 333, 'man-data', "idle", true);
        manAnimation.animationState.setAnimation(0, "in", true)
to 
const manAnimation = this.add.spine(333, 333, 'man-data', "man-atlas", true);
        manAnimation.animationState.setAnimation(0, "in", true
and now i get 

@esotericsoftware_spine-phaser.js?v=17c8bdfe:8409 Uncaught Error: Bone name must not be null.

Comment: somethig wrong with the model? you can reference to this example: https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/spine-runtimes/blob/4.1/spine-ts/spine-phaser/example/typescript/index.ts